# User selection using cookies, first page refresh does not remember

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have some code which is working perfectly after the second page refresh. Basically I have a drop down selection, the selection appends a sort order to the end of the URL,upon the selection of this sort order the page is refreshed.

Here is where my problem is on this post back the cookie does not seem to keep the users selection, however subsequent page refreshes or even through the paging of the catalouge the cookie keep the users selection which is perfect, it's just that first page load after the selection.

Here is the code I have

```
<!-- List header -->
<select id="Selection" class="sorter" onchange="document.cookie= 'myDDIdx = ' + this.selectedIndex + '; path=/;';location=this.options[[this.selectedIndex]].value" style="float:right;margin-right:8px;">
 <option value="">Sort by</option>
 <option value="?orderby=0">Code</option>
 <option value="?orderby=1">Title A-Z</option>
 <option value="?orderby=2">Title Z-A</option>
 <option value="?orderby=3">Brand</option>
 <option value="?orderby=4">Lowest price</option>
 <option value="?orderby=5">Highest price</option>
 <option value="?orderby=6">Lowest Quantity</option>
 <option value="?orderby=7">Highest Quantity</option>
 </select>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>


 <script>
     var sidx = document.cookie.indexOf("myDDIdx");
      if(sidx != -1)
          window.onload = function () { document.getElementById("Selection").selectedIndex =                     document.cookie.substr(sidx + 8,1); }
 </script>
```

Is anyone able to suggest how I can fix this behavior? Code snip-its are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the way you were obtaining the cookie wasn't working correctly. I've changed the code slightly to work properly. Also note when changing the page use `window.location` not just location.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var cookies = document.cookie,
        sidx = !!cookies ? cookies.match(/myDDIdx=([0-9]+?);?/) : false;

    if (!!sidx && sidx.length >= 2) {
        document.getElementById("Selection").selectedIndex = sidx[1];
    }
};

document.getElementById("Selection").onchange = function () {
    document.cookie = 'myDDIdx=' + this.selectedIndex + '; path=/;';
    window.location = this.options[[this.selectedIndex]].value;
};
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8TVwz/7/)

Comment: Thanks for this - though its now not working with an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null Catalogue.aspx?orderby=2:1093
window.onload

Comment: @user2034164 I've updated the code, it shouldn't do that anymore.

Comment: demo is giving error {"error": "Please use POST request"} @AdamMerrifield